# Login With Facebook: My Business verified. However, when I link to the app it says "Unverified"

Tags: reactjs, facebook

I have tried very hard and tried everything but there is still no way to fix this problem.
Can someone tell me what problem I'm having?

Is there any way to fix it?

Or does someone have another way to use the **login with facebook** feature without business verification?

Help me please!

Tôi đã thử mọi cách có thể, bao gồm xoá app và tạo lại.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.